# R renv vs Python virtual environments vs Julia environments

Tags: python, r, julia, virtualenv, virtualization

Are the three cited "virtualisations" solutions ([renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) for R, [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for Python and [environments](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/environments/) for Julia) comparable, in the sense that they try to answer to the same needs (project isolation, reproducibility,...) and provide the same "solutions" or do they significantly differ in scopes and/or implementation ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I cannot answer for `renv`, as I have no experience with it. But I can at least talk about the difference between Python virtual environments and Julia environments.

As you surmised, Python virtual environments and Julia environments answer to the same needs: project isolation and reproducibility (and all stuff generally associated with environments). However, they answer to those needs in very different ways.

Python virtual environments are basically folders containing a *full copy* of the Python stack used to create them, i.e. they contain a separate `python` executable, the full stack associated with it, and a separate `site-packages` folder to contain all the Python packages installed in that environment, included a separate copy of `pip` and `setuptools`. That's how full isolation is achieved: each environment handles installation of packages fully independently. To use a virtual environment, you `activate` them, which consists in temporarily preprending the path to the folder containing that specific Python executable to your PATH environment variable, so that running `python` on the command line runs the right version. This makes Python virtual environments relatively easy to understand and use, but relatively heavyweight, since you basically have a full copy of the Python stack, including a full set of packages (with possibly lots of duplicated packages in multiple environments), for each environment you create.

Julia, on the other hand, was built with environment management built in. It's part and parcel of the language rather than an add-on as with Python. Because of that, environments are handled from within the language itself. A Julia environment, then, is just a folder with a `Project.toml` inside. That's all. Julia packages are installed in a location called a *depot*, where multiple versions of the same package can co-exist. When you `add` a package to a Julia environment, Julia (after dependency resolution) first checks whether the needed version of the package in question is already in the depot. If it is, it will use that version of the package. Only if the needed version of the needed package is missing will it download it. This means that a version of a package will only be installed once, and multiple environments can reuse the same package while still being isolated from each other. *Activating* an environment in Julia simply means making it use the `Project.toml` in that particular folder to decide which packages to use. This architecture makes Julia environments particularly lightweight. Also, it allows what one calls "stacked environments", where you can basically activate multiple environments, and Julia will choose which package to use by searching them all in turn (as it happens, in general when you run Julia with an environment activated, it's always stacked on the default environment, which is always activated).

I hope this helps. As you can see, Python virtual environments and Julia environments couldn't be more different from an implementation point of view.

Comment: The Julia approach also has the (sometimes unfortunate) consequence that Julia versions cannot themselves be managed by the environment.

Comment: True @phipsgabler. I actually wanted to mention that but forgot, so thanks for doing so. And while you're correct, my experience is that using a version manager like https://asdf-vm.com/#/ pretty much solves that problem.

Comment: With Julia 1.7, you the manifest.toml will now store the julia version used to create it: https://julialang.org/blog/2021/11/julia-1.7-highlights/#new_manifest_format

Answer (score 4):

To answer from the R / `renv` side: by default, R loads packages from the library paths as declared (or set) by the `.libPaths()` function, which generally includes a user-specific library path, zero or more site library paths, and a system library.

For example, on macOS with R 4.0.3, I see:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Users/kevinushey/Library/R/4.0/library"
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

And those library paths are shared by all R sessions. All `renv` does is make it easy to set project-local library paths, so that within an `renv` project you might instead see:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Users/kevinushey/scratch/project/renv/library/macos/R-4.0/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0"
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

Normally, these project-local library paths are set by the `renv` auto-loader written to a project `.Rprofile` (read and executed by R when it is started), or explicitly by a user calling `renv::load("~/path/to/project")`.

`renv` does not do anything to manage or control the version of R used with a project itself, though (at least, not as of version 0.12.3) -- that is left up to the user or administrator. `renv` *does* write the version of R in use when generating a lockfile (capturing the R package dependencies in a project), so in theory front-ends could use that information in order to select an appropriate interpreter to be used with a project, though.

In that sense, `renv` does less than Python and Julia do here, since it only helps manage the R packages used in a project; it (at least not yet) does not provide any tools for associating a particular version of R with a project. However, it's also unique in that it is a standalone R package, as opposed to a toolset built into R itself (as some of Python + Julia's tools are).